# Optimize imports as part of refactoring in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, refactoring

I'm planning to move a widely used class from the non-standard package `mycompany.etc` to the more standard `com.mycompany.etc`. IDEA finds and updates references nicely, but when doing so, it updates import statements in-place without moving them according to the import order. The result is that they end up wildly out of place between all the remaining non-standard imports starting with `mycompany`.

Is there a way to instruct IDEA to move the updated import statement, or better yet, automatically perform an 'optimize imports' on each file where imports were updated during refactoring?

Comment: Won't 'Refactor -> Move' on a package do the trick?

Comment: You can click on a project/package and then Cmd + Alt + O (Optimize imports). It will optimize imports in all classes in that project/package.

Comment: @koto - I'm not moving the entire package, just a few classes. (It's been used pretty much as a dumping ground in the past and will need to be broken up into a number of packages.)

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić - I'm trying to avoid creating noise in diffs. That means I don't want any imports to change in classes not affected by my refactoring (and sadly I'm not working in the ideal world where everything else is already optimized and remains untouched). That said, I didn't know you could do this for entire packages or projects, so thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use "Optimize imports on the fly".
Settings-> General-> Auto import-> Optimize imports on the fly

Comment: I've got that on, but apparently it doesn't apply to refactoring changes made by the IDE itself. It seems to trigger an optimize action only when adding an import as you make manual edits to the code.